# Adding class to EF Model cause compile error "The type or namespace name <className> could not be found"

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms, ado.net

Strange one, I've already added 5 tables with no problem. However, when I try and add my `PostCodesUK` table through my edmx model, it gives me this error message:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'PostCodesUK' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   d:\Ben\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DogWalks\DogWalks\App_Code\WalksModel.Context.cs   33  30  DogWalks
```

Not sure what is happening but there are some subtle differences. For example, if I look under the `WalksModel.tt` classes, I can see the PostCodesUK class, but it hasn't generated the additional 'stub':

[image]

If I then double click the error above, it takes me to the `WalksModel.Context.cs` where I see this error:
[image]

I've looked at the `namespace` under the `PostCodesUK.cs` class, which matches the other classes. Does anyone know what the issue is? I have searched online for the issue but could not find a solution.

**Update:** This is what the PostCodeUK class looks like:

```
namespace DogWalks.App_Code
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class PostCodesUK
    {
        public int PostcodeID { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
        public decimal Latitude { get; set; }
        public decimal Longitude { get; set; }
        public string PostcodeNoSpace { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Furthermore,** I've added another temporary table (Person) to my model to test it and it's also giving me the same error message as PostCodesUK:

```
public virtual DbSet<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
...
public virtual DbSet<PostCodesUK> PostCodesUKs { get; set; } //error
public virtual DbSet<Person> People { get; set; } //error
```

Comment: I up-voted this as I have had the same issue in the past; but can't remember how I resolved it.

Comment: What does PostCodesUK class look like? Check that it's public. Check that's the namespace is not also PostCodesUK (because then you'll need to type DbSet<PostCodesUK.PostCodesUK>). If not check that you don't already have the namespace PostCodesUK somewhere in your solution.

Comment: @tzachs thanks for the comment. I've added the class now to the answer (the class generally looks like all the other classes (namespace is identical). Oddly, when I try and add another class I get the same error coming up, which may rule out the namespace conflict? The

Comment: @Brian thanks. This is bizarre. I've just tried to add another new table and it's also giving me the same error message... very odd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok after spending countless hours trying to find a solution I may have actually solved it (touch-wood).

I got frustrated so I deleted my `edmx` model. Reading online, I found there was a bug with `VS 2012` when the edmx model was saved in a subfolder (not in the root). So this might be something to try if my solution below doesn't work, although I managed to keep it in a subfolder.

**Anyway, after deleting my model:**

1. I readded the whole database model to a **new** folder called DAL. When I tried to compile, I noticed ALL of my classes were now throwing the same error.
2. I changed all of the `build action` for all the classes (From `Content` to `Compile`)
3. Rebuilt app and it worked.

**So to put it to the test I tried:**

1. Adding another table to my model, `Person`.
2. Tried to compile (it actually compiled ok) but when I looked at the Person.cs file under Model.tt I saw the stub was once again missing:

[image]

3. I changed the `Build Action` setting to Compile, saved, closed VS and reopened it and the stub appeared correctly:
   [image]

I don't know if that was the issue, but it seems to be working. I didn't check my original case but I have a suspicion that I changed the `.cs` compile mode for my original classes, but not for the newly added classes.

I'm just glad I held off from turning my machine into scrap metal.

Comment: This! Helped! I changed from `Compile` to `Content` rebuild solution and then back again to `Compile` And the stub was present and no errors!

Comment: Same experience with VS 2017 Preview. Two entities from a db first model with 15 entities were displaying these exact same errors. I had to delete and then re-add the two offending entities from the edmx model every time I reopened the solution.  This seems to have fixed the problem.

Comment: After recreating edmx, close and re-open VS helped.